# Android JSOUP get elements of Table

Tags: android, html, jsoup

There is a list of footballers and theirs images and detail links.
How can i get these infos via jsoup for android?

I need href, src, player name

http://www.trabzonspor.org.tr/default.asp?Sayfa=Sporcular&IND=1#Icerik

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" 
bordercolor="#9DC5EC" width="32%" id="AutoNumber54" height="1%">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="100%" height="118">
                
<a href="?Sayfa=SporcuDetay&amp;IND=586#Icerik">
                
<img border="0" src="/Upload/Sporcu/kucuk/14_08_2015-7S4D.jpg" width="136" height="118" 
style="FILTER: alpha(opacity=30)" onmouseover="nereidFade(this,100,70,15)" onmouseout="nereidFade(this,30,80,9)">
</a>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100%" height="25" bgcolor="#4F0000"> <p align="center"><b><font face="Arial" size="1" color="#FFFFFF">
Esteban Alvarado Brown </font></b></p></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Do you have any code to share with us or you just want some one to do the work for you?

Comment: Indeed i have several tries but i couldnt find a good result, so if someone gives a working code, it will more fine

Comment: Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.trabzonspor.org.tr/default.asp?Sayfa=Sporcular&IND=1#Icerik/").get();
            Elements player = doc.select("table#AutoNumber54");
            for(Element p : player ){

            }

Answer (score 0):

```
I have solved, it is working
```

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.trabzonspor.org.tr/default.asp?Sayfa=Sporcular&IND=1#Icerik/").get();
            //id si AutoNumber34 olan table ları alıyoruz. Sorgu sonucunda 34 adet veri geliyor....
            Elements player = doc.select("table#AutoNumber54");
            for (Element p : player) {
                // a href etiketini alıyoruz.....
                Elements linkHref = p.select("a[href]");
                // img with src ending .jpg
                Elements image = p.select("img[src$=.jpg]");

                //başına href yazmamızın nedeni linke tamamıyla ulaşabilmek....
                String absHref = linkHref.attr("abs:href");
                String imagee = image.attr("abs:src");



            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```